# Google Drive Share access to other email address for oAuth 2 using API

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-docs-api

Is it possible to share google drive access of other email address using oAuth2 and javascript client API?

If I have both of other's emailaddress and password?
If using Service account?

I just want to create an app that will allow other Google Signed In users to see and manage my files and directories.

Let me know what is your idea, best practices, steps on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so we are clearn here person one is the person who would like to share something on their drive with person two.

Your application uses oauth2 to authenticate person one. Then you use the [Permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions) method to insert permissions for Person two into what ever file or folder you wish to share with them.  Its person one who has to do this.

Notes:

Service accounts dont work with JavaScript client side you would need to use a server sided language.  Service accounts are a dummy user you would be granting the service account access and not person two.

You cant share the whole drive you cant share the root folder.  You could write a script that shares everything under root.   But someone else cant write to your root folder.

Comment: Person two is the one who will Sign In using browser.. How can I give Person two a permission using Person one account?

Comment: You cant.   Person two needs person one to grant them access first.   Then when person two logs in to google drive they will have access to the files.   In order to access private data.  You need to be logged in with the person who has access to the data or you add shareing as i mentioned.

Comment: Ok. so here is my understanding, first, person one will login and grant person two an access to his files. Then person two login. Then what next? How to list and access files and directories shared by person one?

Comment: This is starting to turn into another question now but you do a [file.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) and use the q parameter looking for sharedwithme. check out [search-parameters](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters)